# @PostConstruct doesn't work if are declared only action method

Tags: spring, jsf, annotations, jsf-2, postconstruct

guys i'm using jsf 2.0 with spring.
I have annotated a method in a managed bean with @PostConstruc, but if in the bean there aren't field connected to the jsf page the @PostConstruct method isn't called even if in the jsf page there is an action method connected to the Bean.
Thank you in advance.

Added code for explaination:

this si my BackingManagedBean

```
@ManagedBean(name="utenteBean")
@ViewScoped
public class UtenteBean extends SupportBean implements Serializable
```

While this is my ControllerManagedBean

```
@ManagedBean(name="gestisciUtentiController")
@ViewScoped
public class GestisciUtentiController extends MessageSupportBean implements Serializable {

@ManagedProperty(value="#{utenteBean}")
private UtenteBean utenteBean;
public void setUtenteBean(UtenteBean utenteBean) {
    this.utenteBean = utenteBean;
}

    @PostConstruct
    public void loadBean()
    {
        try
        {
            utenteBean.setUtentis(getFacadeFactory().getUtenteFacade().readAllOrdered(Utente.class, "username"));
        }
        catch (ApplicationException e)
        {
            setExceptionMessage(e.getLocalizedMessage(), e.getLocalizedMessageDetail());
        }
    }
```

Comment: How exactly is `@PostConstruct` useful if you don't have anything which renders to the view? You have basically nothing to prepare then. What kind of code do you have there? What's the functional requirement?

Comment: I'm trying to have different type of managed bean, for example i have ModelManagedBean that have all the properties of the page and ControllerManagedBean that have action Method. Now i think that in the ControllerManagedBean I must call a postConstruct method that initialize, for example, ModelManagedBean's List object

Comment: Make the model a property of the controller. It shouldn't be a `@ManagedBean` then.

Comment: http://blog.icefaces.org/blojsom/blog/default/2009/04/23/Making-distinctions-between-different-kinds-of-JSF-managed-beans/ i'm trying to use this approch.  You think that that approch isn't correct?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> http://blog.icefaces.org/blojsom/blog/default/2009/04/23/Making-distinctions-between-different-kinds-of-JSF-managed-beans/ i'm trying to use this approch. You think that that approch isn't correct? –

I'm not sure. That article mentions that the model is typically to be placed in the session scope. This is actually a poor approach. Injecting a session scoped bean in a request scoped bean makes sense if the session scoped one is for example the logged-in user and the request scoped one is bound to the form.

In your case you should just make the model bean a property of the controller bean and use `#{gestisciUtentiController.utenteBean.someProperty}` instead of `#{utenteBean.someProperty}`.

I've some "JSF design" questions before, you may find them useful as well:

- [JSF MVC design question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5706128/jsf-mvc-design-question)
- [JSF / Java Design Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4683447/jsf-java-design-question)
- [What components are MVC in JSF MVC framework?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5104094/what-components-are-mvc-in-jsf-mvc-framework)